# Creating class instances stored in a list

Tags: java, reflection, instance

So first I make an `ArrayList`. (`?` means that I don't know what should be there, keep reading)

```
ArrayList<?> arrayList = new ArrayList<?>();
```

So this will store class name of abstract class `Class`, so for example it might stores `ExtendedClass1` or `ClassExtended2`.

Later I iterate through that `ArrayList` and create new objects with the name stored in `arraylist`

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    new arrayList.get(i); // Takes the class name and makes new object out of it
}
```

How can I actually do it?

Comment: So when arrayList contains objects of that class then when iterating could "gardens.get(i).getClass().newInstance();" do it?

Comment: What do you want to store in the list exactly? Names? Why not a list of Strings? Classes? Why not a list of Class<?>?

Comment: Am I right that you want to create instances of yet unknown classes? This, in general, is not easy. You should restrict the classes to some base or interface, providing a known method to call for creating instances (or a pre-defined constructor signature). However, it i **highly** likely that your have an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem]) here and there is a much better solution to the original goal. So please tell us for what exactly you need it. Currently the question is a bit **unclear**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store `String` class names, and then use reflection to create instances, assuming it's reflection that you're going to use:

```
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add("fully.qualified.ExtendedClass1");
arrayList.add("fully.qualified.ClassExtended2");
```

And then, in your loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(arrayList.get(i)); //Get class for the name

    Object instance = cls.newInstance();
    ...
}
```

Comment: worth keeping in mind the classloading issues and how to deal with class not found

Comment: And the fact that a default constructor is not always available. Problem can be limited by defining a base class, a known constructor signature or an interface declaring some `getInstance` method. However, I think we actually have a **XY problem** here.

Comment: @diginoise 100%, I didn't even deal with checked exceptions, but all that applies too.

Comment: @Zabuza "Reflection" is **assumed** in this answer, as mentioned.